# automate the import of private keys into phantom/solflare

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, phantom, dapp

I need to automate the interaction between a dapp and a solana wallet, does anyone know if its possible to import multiple wallets into solflare/phantom at once ?

Just curious does anyone know how the following site can help check the amount of airdrop for this site ? https://airdrop.jup.ag/ and is this also doable when we are claiming the airdrop token as well ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you enter a seed phrase Phantom will automatically import all accounts that have any transaction history. A part from this, it is not currently possible to automate importing multiple accounts into Phantom.